# My Access DB will not update. No errors in code

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

I am using this code to update the database:

```cs
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
string commandString = string.Empty;
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandString, con);
    commandString = "UPDATE accesscontrol SET enabled=@isEnabled WHERE proxyFor=@userNameInGrid AND currentlyLoggedOnUser=@userName";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", Environment.UserName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("isEnabled", tempPerson.isBool.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userNameInGrid", tempPerson.Name);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you use empty `commandString`

First, you set:

```
string commandString = string.Empty;
```

And then you passed empty `commandString` to `OleDbCommand`, after that you set the value to variable `commandString` but not to `OleDbCommand`

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandString, con);
commandString = "UPDATE accesscontrol SET enabled=@isEnabled WHERE proxyFor=@userNameInGrid AND currentlyLoggedOnUser=@userName";
```

Change you code to:

```
commandString = "UPDATE accesscontrol SET enabled=@isEnabled WHERE proxyFor=@userNameInGrid AND currentlyLoggedOnUser=@userName";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandString, con);
```

**UPDATE**

Also, you should add `@` before the parameter name

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isEnabled", tempPerson.isBool.ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNameInGrid", tempPerson.Name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Environment.UserName);
```

**Note**: as @LarsTech mentioned, OleDB does not use named parameters correctly. The parameters have to be added in the same index order they appear in the SQL statement

Comment: @softwareisfun Any news? Was it helpful?

Comment: OleDB does not use named parameters correctly.  The parameters have to be added in the same index order they appear in the SQL statement, so `@isEnabled` should be first, etc.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, I added it to the answer.